# Simple HTML to vertically "stack" pages from other URLs (resulting in long scrolling)?

Tags: html, url, csv, src

I have a URL that returns data in CSV format, and I'd like to download a lot of data from the site, but it only allows narrow time windows in each data pull.  The parameters are in the URL, so I can quickly and automatically generate a bunch of different URLs that taken together would pull all the data I'm looking for, but it would take a lot to do each one manually.

Is there a simple way I can create an HTML file on my computer that will vertically stack the contents of each URL?  Then I can copy the display of my "page" to a text file, and have a CSV file with all the data.

I've tried:

```
<HTML>
  <FRAMESET>
    <FRAME src="URL1">
    <FRAME src="URL2">
    ...
  </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

but it only showed the data from URL1.  Looking at examples of frame usage, it seems they're designed to partition the screen and scrolling would be inside each frame.  I suspect this stacked my frames in a layered manner, which won't allow me to copy/paste the page contents to a text file.

I've also tried `<DIV src="URL1"></DIV>...`, but no go on that either.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how many frames you wish to have on your page, it might be cleaner to place them into tab containers: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/D3XUL/.

However, if all you want to do is create a collection of frames on your page that are vertically stacked, you were most of the way there.  You would want to use `<iframe>`'s instead of `<frameset>` and `<frame>`, as those are both deprecated in HTML5.  Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/2aD3C/).

Comment: I'm not up to speed on HTML5 and never heard of iframes until doing my searches before posting this question.  I tried them quickly too (2 iframes), but it looked like it divided the screen area into 2 row by 8 columns and then put the two frames in the first two cells of the top row, each with their own scroll bar, so I disregarded them.  I'll check out that example.

Comment: I like the iframes example, but I'd like to allow them to be as wide as they'd care to be (100% or more, with a single horizontal scrollbar for the entire page if needed), and as tall as they'd like to be - to help with the massive copy, paste, I'd like to avoid individual scrollbars in the iframes, I'd like them to stitch together end to end so that you can't tell they're not one single page.

Comment: The last bit of that is going to be very easy with HTML5, just add `seamless` to the end of the `<iframe>` tag.  The width and height, however, you'll have to do with a bit of jQuery.  The `<iframe>` element does not support relative heights/widths (e.g., 100%), so you will have to grab the content, have jQuery pull the height/width, and then dynamically change the `height=""` and `width=""` attributes on your iframes.

n.b., browser support for `seamless` is currently limited, I believe, to WebKit-based browsers (e.g., Safari and Chrome).

Comment: I've been reading up on the iframe at www.w3schools.com. Regardless of the specification saying it only takes pixels, I got width="100%" to work.  I see that seamless is limited, which is fine since I'm using Chrome, but it doesn't behave like I expect.  If my cursor is inside one of the iframes, Ctrl+A selects everything INSIDE the frame, but not the whole page.  Any attempt to select and copy the whole page, doesn't grab the data inside the frame when I try to paste.  This is headed in the right direction, but short of the "select all, paste into text file" that I was hoping for.

Comment: Another possible way to accomplish your goal would be to create a jQuery script which calls each of the URLs from which you want to capture data (or runs on the click of a button and processes a list of URLs in a text field on a page) and then appends the data from each URL to the page itself.  You could then format that data fairly easily into a table or whatever other display element you prefer.